# Showing previously added values from a DB in a view in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the Lynda.com tutorial on Ruby on Rails. While following it, when asked to make a form, I used normal HTML code rather than using the form_for method. So my form now looks like below where I have used an array of parameters to pass the values. Since this is my edit.html.erb file, I have also declared an value field where I will be displaying the previous data value.

Now if for example my name is equal to "My long Name". In the edit view only "My" part is displayed. i.e only the first part of the subject name is displayed.

Note: I also have a 'show' view where I list out details of a particular subject. There the full name("My long name") is displayed correctly.

So why cant I get it to work here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <div class="subjects index">
    <h2>Update Subject</h2>   
    <form action="/subjects/<%= @subject.id %>" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 l5">
          <input id="name" name="subject[name]" value= <%= @subject.name %> type="text" class="validate" >
          <label for="name" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Update Subject" />
      </div>

      <%= link_to("Back",'/subjects',:class => 'action index') %>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the quotation marks after the `value` parameter of the name input.

Without them you get the HTML: `<input id="name" name="subject[name]" value=My long name type="text" class="validate" >`

So the `long` and `name` becomes attributes them self as well (they are valid custom valid attributes in HTML5).

It should work like this:
 `<input id="name" name="subject[name]" value="<%= @subject.name %>" type="text" class="validate" >`

But please use the built in `form` and `input` helpers, that is considered as best practice. They generate all the necessary HTML with less effort.

Answer (score 1):

`<input id="name" name="subject[name]" value="<%= @subject.name %>" type="text" class="validate" >`

or in other words, the 'value' of input should be surrounded with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use Rails'es built-in `form_for` helper method? Rails is used to generate HTML dynamicaly using ruby, not to create HTML manualy. 
You would then just have:

```
<%= render 'form', subject: @subject %>
```

which would resolve your problem automatically

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question, you're right that by not using Rails' helpers is an anti pattern.

Comment: I am using materialize as the front end. and when I tried to style the form, it didnt turn out as I'd like to. But tbh I only tried to combine those two at a time where I didnt have much knowledge about using RoR efficiently. 

So, I'll give it another go as I also understand that the built in method is the way to go forward. Thanks alot!